# Best practice to communicate/send data between unity apps?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mono

I want to set up a communication channel(even one-way communication works) between two unity apps (Windows to Android or Android to Android), like sending strings/binary.

So far I have found answers which suggest

- Photon (not sure if I should go for this since I only need to send a string)
- TCP (a C# TCP/IP is an option I am thinking about)
- Bluetooth (haven't found anything related to a Bluetooth connection between unity apps)
- Any other option?

I would appreciate it if you can share any resources on this.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you are trying to achieve by sending this message between devices?

Comment: @Ron  , for now, I want to send information like if a particular button was clicked, but if permitted I think what best describes my use case is texting between devices.

Comment: It sounds that you will need some sort of a server as a middle man. Whether it's some web API, TCP listener or 3rd party service.

Comment: @Ron any particular name/example comes to mind?

Comment: PUN (Photon) is a 3rd party service, there are plenty others out there. You can also use Unity's built in networking + master server. You can deploy your own API/TCP server, but I would highly recommend against this unless you have a good reason and available resources.